# Get all values before a decimal number from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, list, floating-point, pattern-matching

I have a list of strings which come from the variable `newresult` in my code below. Example:

```
['Naproxen  500  Active ingredient  Ph Eur',
 'Croscarmellose sodium  22.0  Disintegrant  Ph Eur',
 'Povidone K90  11.0 mg  Binder  Ph Eur',
 'Water, purifieda',
 'Silica, colloidal anhydrous  2.62 %  Glidant  Ph Eur',
 'Magnesium stearate  1.38  Lubricant  Ph Eur',
 'Hypromellose 3 mPas  5.10  Film former  Ph Eur 20%']
```

From here, I want to get all values (medicine names) that are present before a decimal number from the string. If a decimal number is not found in the string, I want to get all values (medicine names) before a number. If a number is not present, I want to get the medicine names from regex groups. If any percentage data is present, I want it as a separate entity So, I want 4 things from each string,

```
Medicine name- name of the medicine
Dosage - The decimal value in the string. If no decimal value, then dosage is the number value in the string
Activity- Remaining part of the string without medicine name and dosage.
Dosage percentage - Any number/decimal with percentage attached to it.
```

Expected output:

```
Medicine name                   Dosage          All Role                   Dosage Percentage

Naproxen                         500         Active ingredient  Ph Eur
Croscarmellose sodium            22.0        Disintegrant  Ph Eur
Povidone K90                     11.0 mg        Binder  Ph Eur
Water, purifieda                              
Silica, colloidal anhydrous                    Glidant  Ph Eur                  2.62%                                     
Magnesium stearate               1.38         Lubricant  Ph Eur
Hypromellose 3 mPas              5.10         Film former  Ph Eur                 20%
```

Code till now:

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\lat.csv', 'r')
oo=csv.reader(file)
allsub = []
for line in oo:
    allsub.append(line)

medicines = [item for sublist in allsub for item in sublist]    

files = open(r'C:\Users\1060099.csv', 'r')
oos=csv.reader(files)

allrole = []
for line in oos:
    allrole.append(line[2]) 

allrole = list(set(allrole))
allrole.remove('Active')    



def tableextract(filename):
    file=open(filename, encoding ='utf8')
    file=file.read()
    result = []
    med = r"(?:{})".format("|".join(map(re.escape, medicines)))
    pattern = re.compile(r"^\s*" + med + r".*(?:\n[^\w\n]*\d*\.?\d+(?:\s*[dkm]g|kg|ml|q\.s\.|gm|µg)?[^\w\n]*(?:\n.*){2})?", re.M|re.IGNORECASE)

    result = pattern.findall(file)
    results = [item.replace("\t", " ") for item in result]
    resultsn = [item.replace("\xa0", " ") for item in results]
    nresults = [item.replace("\n", " ") for item in resultsn]
    newresult = []
    for line in nresults:
        newresult.append((line.strip()))

    med_reg = r"({})".format("|".join(map(re.escape, medicines)))
    pattern_med = re.compile(r"^\s*" + med_reg + r".*(?:\n[^\w\n]*\d*\.?\d+(?:\s*[dkm]g|kg|ml|q\.s\.|gm|µg)?[^\w\n]*(?:\n.*){2})?", re.M|re.IGNORECASE)
    medicine_only = []
    for matcher in pattern_med.finditer(file):
        medicine_only.append(matcher.group(1))
```

The issue is with this part of the code below:

```
    Rx = r"(?i)(?=.*?((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)\s*(?:mg|kg|ml|q\.s\.|gm|µg)))?(?=.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*%))?(?=.*?((?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+))(?![\d.])(?!\s*(?:%|mg|kg|ml|gm|q\.s\.|µg)))?.+"
    final = []
    for s in medicine_only:
        for e in newresult:
            match = re.search( Rx, e )
            if e.upper().startswith(s.upper()):
                if match.group(1) and match.group(2):
                    final.append([s,match.group(1), match.group(2), e])

                elif match.group(2) and match.group(3):
                    final.append([s,match.group(3), match.group(2), e])
                elif match.group(1):
                    final.append([s,match.group(1),'', e])
                elif match.group(2):
                    final.append([s,'',match.group(2), e])
                else:
                    if match.group(3):
                        #ee = match.group(3)
                        if isinstance(match.group(3), float):                            
                            final.append([s,match.group(3),'', e])


    res = []
    for sub in final:
        new_sub = sub
        agent_found = False
        for ag in allrole:
            if agent_found:
                break
            for item in sub:
                if ag.lower() in item.lower():
                    new_sub = [ag] + new_sub
                    agent_found = True
                    break
        if not agent_found:
            new_sub = [" "] + new_sub
        res.append(new_sub)

    return res
```

It is either returning null or only a few values and not all values from `newresult` which it should have done. The expected output is not obtained from here. Can anyone help me fix this part of the code or get the expected output from the input list of string without fixing this part of the code